# Java: preventing deadlock in this example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Trying to exercise my understanding of concurrency in Java, here's the problem:
There can be multiple threads running method A and only one thread running method B (lets say when A() has run for 10 times. So on the 10th time, that thread will run method B. When this happens, it must block threads from running A and allow threads that are already running A complete before running the rest of B. Also, the threads in A shouldn't wait on itself.

edit: All threads are started on A first, there is an outside method that checks when to run B.

My attempt so far looks something like this:

```
volatile Boolean lock = false; //false = threads in method A allowed to run, thread in method B otherwise
volatile Integer countOfA = 0;

void A(){
    boolean continue = false;
    synchronized(lock){
    if(lock == true){ //there is a thread in B, block threads in A
        lock.wait();

        increaseCountOfA();
        //do work
        decreaseCountOfA();

        if(countOfA == 0){ //this was the last thread that ran with lock
            lock = true;
            lock.notify(); //only the thread in B should be waiting on this
        }
      }else{
        continue = true;
      }
    }

    if(continue){
        increaseCountOfA();
        //do work;
        decreaseCountOfA();
    }
}

void B(){
  synchronized(lock){
    if(lock == false){
        lock.wait();
        if(countOfA > 0){
            countOfA.wait();
        }
        //do work;
        lock = false;
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}

void increaseCountOfA(){
  synchronized(countOfA){
    countOfA++;
  }
}

void decreaseCountOfA(){
  synchronized(countOfA){
    countOfA--;
  }
}
```

When its ran, it hangs. I'm suspecting a deadlock also I don't know how many levels of synchronization is needed for this problem. Can this be done with just one level?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not thing that with this code the vairable 'lock' ever get's to be set to true, so probably all your threads are waiting on it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Initialized it to true but its behavior is still unchanged.

Comment: @Belov Actually, lock is meant to be false at first to allow threads to do work in A first, notice the else in A().

Comment: I know it is init to false, and is sup to be, but I think you should change it to true I'd guess somewhere in the B() method. At the moment you are putting lock=true in the if(lock==true) statement only and since lock is init to false it never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `synchronized(lock)` you are synchronizing on the object referred to by `lock`, not on the variable. You probably want an independent lock object whose value you are not changing. Alternately, you might consider using a higher-level concurrency class like `Semaphore`.

In this case, you have one thread waiting on `Boolean.TRUE`, and another posting a notify on `Boolean.FALSE`.

Comment: wouldn't having a constant object for lock make the threads in A execute sequentially since they're all synchronized on it? Those synchronized blocks probably shouldn't be that big to begin with.

Comment: All of your thread A's will wait on the lock. Since `wait()` releases the monitor, as soon as one thread waits the others are free to enter the `synchronized` block. Then `notify()` is never called because all the thread A's are blocked, and thread B calls `notify()` only if `lock` is somehow false.